"There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox" Visual Studio 2022
I'm trying to make a clr project but when i use toolbox, it shows me "There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox".
I've tried to right click on Toolbox, choose "Show All", but all tools are shown in grey characters, and i can't do anything with it, without some "Data" tools like pointer, dataset,...
(https://i.sstatic.net/gws5LMTI.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/TMIIX4lJ.png)

What type of project you are working on?To enable toolbox you must working on a form or a UserControl in design mode so you can use toolbox.

I'm using a clr empty project

To show available controls you have to work on a corresponding project as I previously mentioned.If you accidently deleted your tools in toolbox then you can right click any tools and select "Choose item"or "Reset toolbox"to get your tools back.
